# ASP.NET Login Control with Active Directory Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, authentication, membership-provider

I have setup a basic application which uses the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to talk to our AD and authenticate users. It's a simple login page with the control which redirects me to a simple output of who is logged in and associated ticket information, this works great and when I test it on my development machine it just works.

However if I deploy this to the webserver under a virtual directory, it simple refuses to direct or even acknowledge that there ticket is a valid ticket, it just refreshes back to the login page. If I type in rubbish credentials it actually recognises this and tells me there';s an error, but if I login successfully it just refreshes the page. When I manually go the information page it treats me as an unauthenticated user!

This is most puzzling! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Jon

As requested a section of the Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ActiveDirectory" connectionString="LDAP://x.x.x.117:389/OU=Users,DC=BC,DC=Local"/>
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
<providers>

<add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ActiveDirectory" connectionUsername="xxxxxx" connectionPassword="xxxxxxx" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" applicationName="/"/>

</providers>

</membership>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting on the ASP.NET tracer to see what details are coming back from a successful login?

Comment: In addition, have you turned on impersonation in the web.config file?

Comment: This is the screwed up bit if I deploy it as the root application as in no virtual directory it does work!!! This is a slightly odd situation as this application talks ad-hoc to the AD (using a username that has readonly access to the tree, looks at a container) and the webserver does not login in through the AD for authentication itself... I am not sure if this affects anything?

Comment: However to answer your question...  impersonation is not enabled, but I will try...

Comment: Hmmm, I took a different approach than use the AD Membership Provider, so I'm not sure about the issue with the virtual directory. Can you update the question with the web.config pertaining to the membership provider?

Comment: KICK ASS!! Thanks the impersonation entry worked!!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<forms slidingExpiration="true" **path="/Search"** name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="10"/>
```

It was also helpful to include a 'path' attribute!!!!

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on impersonation in the web.config file? I belive there are some issues revolving the membership provider that need impersonation to work properly.